# I am trying to make a 5x5 tic tac toe program in C but facing some problem in looping I think. The program automatically displays player 1 as winner

Tags: c, loops, do-while, tic-tac-toe

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

char square[26] = {'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};
char row[5] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
char column[5] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
int playingChoice;


int checkWin();
void board();

int main()
{

    
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\t\t\t**** T I C   T A C   T O E ****\n");
    printf("\n\n");
    
    printf("Press 1 for Player Vs Player \nPress 2 for Player Vs Computer\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &playingChoice);
    
    //Human player Vs Human player Code
    if(playingChoice == 1){
        int player = 1, i, choiceRow, choiceColumn;
        char mark;

    do
    {
        board();
        player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;

        printf("Player %d, choose row :  ", player);
        scanf("%d", &choiceRow);
        printf("Player %d, choose column :  ", player);
        scanf("%d", &choiceColumn);

        mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';

        if (choiceRow == 1 && choiceColumn == 1 && square[1] == ' ')
            square[1] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 1 && choiceColumn == 2 && square[2] == ' ')
            square[2] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 1 && choiceColumn == 3 && square[3] == ' ')
            square[3] = mark;   
        else if (choiceRow == 1 && choiceColumn == 4 && square[4] == ' ')
            square[4] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 1 && choiceColumn == 5 && square[5] == ' ')
            square[5] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 2 && choiceColumn == 1 && square[6] == ' ')
            square[6] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 2 && choiceColumn == 2 && square[7] == ' ')
            square[7] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 2 && choiceColumn == 3 && square[8] == ' ')
            square[8] = mark;   
        else if (choiceRow == 2 && choiceColumn == 4 && square[9] == ' ')
            square[9] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 2 && choiceColumn == 5 && square[10] == ' ')
            square[10] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 3 && choiceColumn == 1 && square[11] == ' ')
            square[11] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 3 && choiceColumn == 2 && square[12] == ' ')
            square[12] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 3 && choiceColumn == 3 && square[13] == ' ')
            square[13] = mark;   
        else if (choiceRow == 3 && choiceColumn == 4 && square[14] == ' ')
            square[14] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 3 && choiceColumn == 5 && square[15] == ' ')
            square[15] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 4 && choiceColumn == 1 && square[16] == ' ')
            square[16] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 4 && choiceColumn == 2 && square[17] == ' ')
            square[17] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 4 && choiceColumn == 3 && square[18] == ' ')
            square[18] = mark;   
        else if (choiceRow == 4 && choiceColumn == 4 && square[19] == ' ')
            square[19] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 4 && choiceColumn == 5 && square[20] == ' ')
            square[20] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 5 && choiceColumn == 1 && square[21] == ' ')
            square[21] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 5 && choiceColumn == 2 && square[22] == ' ')
            square[22] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 5 && choiceColumn == 3 && square[23] == ' ')
            square[23] = mark;   
        else if (choiceRow == 5 && choiceColumn == 4 && square[24] == ' ')
            square[24] = mark;
        else if (choiceRow == 5 && choiceColumn == 5 && square[25] == ' ')
            square[25] = mark;    
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid move ");

            player--;
            getch();
        }
        i = checkWin();

        player++;
    }while (i ==  - 1);
    
    board();
    
    if (i == 1)
        printf("==>\aPlayer %d win ", --player);
    else
        printf("==>\aGame draw");

    getch();

    return 0;

}//end if
}//end int main
        

void board()
{
        system("cls");
        
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\t**** T I C   T A C   T O E ****\n");
        printf("\n\n");
        
        
        printf("\n");
        
        printf("\t\t    Player 1 place [X] | ");
        
        printf("Player 2 place [O]\n\n\n");
         
        printf("\t\t\t     1     2     3     4     5    \n");
        printf("\t\t\t  --------------------------------\n");
        printf("\t\t\t  |     |     |     |     |     | \n");
        
        printf("\t\t\t1 |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n", square[1], square[2], square[3], square[4], square[5]);
    
        printf("\t\t\t  |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|\n");
        
        printf("\t\t\t  |     |     |     |     |     | \n");
    
        printf("\t\t\t2 |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n", square[6], square[7], square[8], square[9], square[10]);
    
        printf("\t\t\t  |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|\n");
        
        printf("\t\t\t  |     |     |     |     |     | \n");
    
        printf("\t\t\t3 |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n", square[11], square[12], square[13], square[14], square[15]);
    
        printf("\t\t\t  |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|\n");
    
        printf("\t\t\t  |     |     |     |     |     | \n");
    
        printf("\t\t\t4 |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n", square[16], square[17], square[18], square[19], square[20]);
    
        printf("\t\t\t  |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|\n");
        
        printf("\t\t\t  |     |     |     |     |     | \n");
        
        printf("\t\t\t5 |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n", square[21], square[22], square[23], square[24], square[25]);
        
        printf("\t\t\t  |     |     |     |     |     | \n");
        printf("\t\t\t  --------------------------------\n");
}

int checkWin()
{

if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3] && square[3] == square[4] && square[4] == square[5]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[6] == square[7] && square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9] && square[9] == square[10]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[11] == square[12] && square[12] == square[13] && square[13] == square[14] && square[14] == square[15]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[16] == square[17] && square[17] == square[18] && square[18] == square[19] && square[19] == square[20]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[21] == square[22] && square[22] == square[23] && square[23] == square[24] && square[24] == square[25]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[1] == square[6] && square[6] == square[11] && square[11] == square[16] && square[16] == square[21]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[2] == square[7] && square[7] == square[12] && square[12] == square[17] && square[17] == square[22]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[3] == square[8] && square[8] == square[13] && square[13] == square[18] && square[18] == square[23]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[4] == square[9] && square[9] == square[14] && square[14] == square[19] && square[19] == square[24]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[5] == square[10] && square[10] == square[15] && square[15] == square[20] && square[20] == square[25]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[1] == square[7] && square[7] == square[13] && square[13] == square[19] && square[19] == square[25]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[5] == square[9] && square[9] == square[13] && square[13] == square[17] && square[17] == square[21]){
        return 1;
    }else if (square[1] != ' ' && square[2] != ' ' && square[3] != ' ' && square[4] != ' ' && square[5] != ' ' && square[6] != ' ' 
              && square[7] != ' ' && square[8] != ' ' && square[9] != ' ' && square[10] != ' ' && square[11] != ' ' && square[12] != ' ' 
              && square[13] != ' ' && square[14] != ' ' && square[15] != ' ' && square[16] != ' ' && square[17] != ' ' && square[18] != ' ' 
              && square[19] != ' ' && square[20] != ' ' && square[21] != ' ' && square[22] != ' ' && square[23] != ' ' && square[24] != ' ' 
              && square[25] != ' '){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return  - 1;
        }
}
```

When the player enteres his desired row and column, the program automatically displays player 1 as the winner. I think the problem might be in looping but I am not sure. Kindly help me in this problem and sorry if you find my code childish since I am a beginner and this is my 2nd month into programming

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger, setting break points, inspecting variables? If not, please do that first and if you still have a question, then add your findings from debugging.

Comment: You have checked for lines of equal values, but not that they are `'X'` or `'O'`. So a line of the intitialised `' '` space characters will be seen as a win.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I believe your input code and display code can be shorter. Here is a [repl](https://replit.com/@depperm/UnsteadyImpeccableProduct#main.c) with shorter code (keep in mind conio.h isn't imported so some functionality won't work like original code)

Answer (score 2):

Weather Vane spells out that your check of "five in a row" is incomplete in that the program is not making sure that the check is for either five X's or five O's.  So taking the first test group in your code for example, instead of the current test

```
    if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3] && square[3] == square[4] && square[4] == square[5])
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

There would be an additional test of one of the elements in the test group not being blank.

```
    if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3] && square[3] == square[4] && square[4] == square[5] && square[1] != ' ')
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Checking one of the elements to ensure that it is not blank in each of the test blocks would need to be repeated for each test group.

Doing that change and purposely entering choices that do not result in "five in a row" produced the final draw outcome on the terminal.

```
            **** T I C   T A C   T O E ****



            Player 1 place [X] | Player 2 place [O]


                 1     2     3     4     5    
              --------------------------------
              |     |     |     |     |     | 
            1 |  X  |  O  |  X  |  O  |  X  |
              |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
              |     |     |     |     |     | 
            2 |  O  |  X  |  O  |  X  |  O  |
              |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
              |     |     |     |     |     | 
            3 |  X  |  O  |  X  |  O  |  X  |
              |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
              |     |     |     |     |     | 
            4 |  O  |  X  |  O  |  X  |  O  |
              |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
              |     |     |     |     |     | 
            5 |  O  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  O  |
              |     |     |     |     |     | 
              --------------------------------
==>Game draw
```

No need to accept this answer.  Just wanted to embellish the previous comment so that it was clear to you.